# Laravel CRUD API Fatal Error: Trait 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I was following this tutorial, but with my own dataset: https://www.positronx.io/php-laravel-crud-operations-mysql-tutorial

And I got stuck on the phase of Creating and storing data.

After filling all the fields:[image: gui]

Im getting this error:[image: hasfactory error]

When I comment use HasFactory it's showing this
[image: commented hasfactory]

Please help!

Comment: go on `Obesity` Model, and comment the line `use HasFactory;`

Comment: It is saying now that Class 'App\Models\Obesity' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HasFactory` trait wasn't introduced until Laravel 8x. That's also when they moved all the models into the `app/Models` directory.

I'm guessing that you're on Laravel 7x (or earlier), which does not have the `HasFactory` trait, and where all the models are stored in the `app` directory by default.

If you want to follow that tutorial, you'll want to start with a Laravel 8x application. If you want to stay on 7x, you'll need to adjust some things to work in 7x. For example, delete the `use` statement for the `HasFactory` trait. Additionally, your models are probably in the `App` namespace, not the `App\Models` namespace.